# How to create a test contract that takes parameters?

Tags: solidity, truffle, unittesting

I have a contract like so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

Contract Ballot {

constructor(string[] memory proposalNames) public {

    }
}
```

How do I create a test-instance of it in solidity?

I tried:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";

import "../contracts/voting.sol";
contract TestVoting {

    function testCounter() public {
     Ballot meta = Ballot(DeployedAddresses.Ballot());


    }

}
```

but i get an error:

```
 1) TestVoting
       testCounter:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:94:1)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

How do I pass it its constructor arguments?

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/159), it doesn't seem like it's possible to create a  parameterized test contract -- is this really the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can just deploy a new instance.

```
function testCounter() public {
     string[] memory params = new string[](3);
     params[0] = "bambino";
     params[1] = "was";
     params[2] = "here";
     Ballot ballot = new Ballot(params);

}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Why do the truffle tests use `DeployedAddress`? https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-solidity

Comment: @nz_21 That's the address deployed by the migrations scripts. It will work if you deployed the contract in the migration scripts.